# How can I get data from the child of a CompositeView?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a CompositeView with a `<header>` and a `<tbody>`. I need specific data from the collection that's added to the `<tbody>` for use in the `<header>`. Specifically, I need to display the TOTAL NUMBER of records in the collection as well as the TOTAL COST of all models (each model has an `amount` attribute with a dollar value, like `54.35`).

How might I do this?

Here is all relative code:

```
/*
 * Layout
 */
var AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "#customer-view",
    regions: {
        card: "#customer-card",
        quotes: "#customer-quotes",
        orders: "#customer-order-history"
    }
});
Show.Layout = new AppLayout();
Show.Layout.render();


/*
 * ItemView
 */
Show.HistoryItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: "#customer-history-item"
});
Show.HistoryItemsView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#customer-history-wrapper",
    itemView: Show.HistoryItemView,
    itemViewContainer: "tbody"
});


/*
 * Items
 */
var customer_orders = Customers.request("customer:orders", UserID);
var customer_orders_view = new Show.HistoryItemsView({
    collection: customer_orders
});
Show.Layout.orders.show(customer_orders_view);
```

… And the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="customer-history-wrapper">
        <div class="module collapsible">
        <header>
            <hgroup>
                <h2>Order History</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <div class="results">
                <div class="left"><strong><%= NUMBER OF RECORDS %></strong> Orders</div>
                <div class="right">$ <%= TOTAL COST OF RECORDS %></div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="module-content no-pad">
            <table class="simple-table six-up" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Licensee</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Order</th>
                        <th class="numeric">Total</th>
                        <th class="cta">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

`<%= NUMBER OF RECORDS %>` and `<%= TOTAL COST OF RECORDS %>` is where I'll need to insert this data.

Appreciate any help I can get!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompositeViews can have a collection and a model, create a model with the properties that you need, on this case numberofRecors, totalCost, 
then on your onBeforeRender function calculate the totals of your model, something like this.

```
var customer_orders_view = new Show.HistoryItemsView({ 
    model: totals,
    collection: customer_orders
});
Show.Layout.orders.show(customer_orders_view);

Show.HistoryItemsView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
template: "#customer-history-wrapper",
itemView: Show.HistoryItemView,
itemViewContainer: "tbody",
onBeforeRender : function () {
    this.model.set({numberOfRecors : this.collection.length});
    //here you can set the model values to be displayed.
}
```

});

you can also pass the model with the values precalculated that way you dont need the on beforeRender function, If you do that when you call show on the region this will call the render function of the compositeView and that will be it. you model will be also rendered alongisde your collection.

Comment: How do I then access `numberOfRecords` in the template?

Comment: if you are using underscore as your template engine using <%= numberOfRecors %> will be enough, as long as the name of the property of your model matches the variable in the template, is just like any other view when you define the <%= %> as the placeholder for the value of your model. this will render that value, but if you want to manipulate the value calling HistoryItemsView.model.get('numberOFRecors')  will give you the value in cae you need it somewhere else.

Comment: Hmm. Very close, but it's returning `0` for the number of records (there are 12).

Comment: try calculating the number of records before you pass the model to the view, if your model already set i think it should work.

Comment: Changing it to `onCompositeCollectionRendered` seemed to work. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: nop, I dont know your code so I dont know when you are fetching your collection so I was assuming things, but if perfectly fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30998/discussion-between-brandon-durham-and-rayweb-on)